# htacces code redirecting and hiding folder problem

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hide, subdirectory

Can anyone help me with an htaccess file?

It is like this:

https://domainname2.com is redirected to
https://domainname1.com/FOLDER-named-as-domainname2/$

Now I would like visitors to only see https://domainname2.com and not https://domainname1.com/FOLDER-named-as-domainname2/$

I currently use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domainname2/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainname2\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /FOLDER-named-as-domainname2/$1 [L]
```

This works... but people continue to see the FOLDER-named-as-domainname2.

I have used various options to 'hide' the folder that I found on this page, but I am probably still doing something wrong because it doesn't work.

Either the folder remains visible, or the page no longer loads at all and goes to the website in the 'root'

Please, can anyone help me with this?

I am eternally grateful!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domainname2/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainname2\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /FOLDER-named-as-domainname2/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+FOLDER-named-as-domainname2/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^folder/)^(.*)$ /FOLDER-named-as-domainname2/$1 [L,NC]`\
```